# Word For When You've Been Forced to No Longer Trust Something or Someone

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, adjectives

Often, I encounter situations (particularly with software or electronics, though occasionally with people) where bugs or strange events happen that cause me to lose trust in said software maintaining the integrity of my data, or said technology being reliable 'in the clutch' (or even scenarios where a person or business entity change a predictable, relied-on pattern of behavior, belief or expectation).

Sometimes I feel so strongly about the broken trust, that I feel forced to stop trusting (even if such events leading to the distrust were unintentional). I may still use said software, but I continue to do so very cautiously at that point.

**The word I believe I'm looking for** is similar to 'ized' words, in that it **describes a state of 'forced distrust' assigned to myself**, not the state or act of the object/person breaking the trust (e.g. "I've been/become xxxxxxxized by such-and-such...").

I often want to use the word 'disenfranchised' to describe such a state, but I'm not sure that's 100% suitable to the various contexts or the concept of lost trust (even though whatever trust I had was likely unfounded anyway, simply because, at least in the context of software, that trust is simply the lack of distrust due to having not yet experienced any bugs/issues that have built up a negative rapport with said software and what I expect it to do without fail).

So what's the word I'm looking for, if such a single word exists?

Comment: Do you think a single word meaning "made suspicious" would fit?  Or something along the lines of "paranoid"?  Paranoid has an implication that the distrust is based on non-rational reasoning, so it's not right, but might be in the right direction.

Comment: Those are okay, but I think the word I'm looking for is perhaps not as common, and sounds a bit more sophisticated (like 'disenfranchised').

Comment: No worries. Faith and trust can potentially have different contextual implications, and there's still value to others searching for this using the term trust, rather than faith, since the other post didn't include 'trust' in the content (which may also explain why my own search came up empty). Cheers.

Comment: *...situations (particularly with software or electronics) where bugs or strange events happen that cause me to lose trust in said software maintaining the integrity of my data, or said technology being reliable 'in the clutch'* Do you mean like [Delta's computer system today](http://www.nbcnews.com/business/travel/delta-system-outage-triggers-delays-worldwide-n625141)?

Comment: Here's what [George W. Bush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKgPY1adc0A) would say: "There's an old saying in Tennessee—I know it's in Texas, probably in Tennessee—that says, 'Fool me once, shame on ... shame on you. It fooled me, we can't get fooled again!'"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're **disillusioned**.

> *disillusioned* adj
>
> having lost one's ideals, illusions, or false ideas about someone or
>   something; disenchanted

{[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disillusioned)}

> *disillusioned* (adjective)  disenchanted, disappointed, enlightened, indifferent, disabused, sadder and wiser ...

{[Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disillusioned)}

Comment: Yes, I believe 'disillusioned' might just be the word I was looking for. 'Sadder and wiser' is painfully humorous, too. Thanks for posting.

Comment: disappointed might be a better fit since it simply denotes the system failed to meet his expectations, without implying his expectations were unrealistic.

Answer (score 7):

You feel [**betrayed**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betray):

> - to hurt (someone who trusts you, such as a friend or relative) by not giving help or by doing something morally wrong
> - to fail or desert especially in time of need

Answer (score 5):

You've **been burned**.

> ## burn
>
> verb (used with object), **burned** or **burnt**, **burning**.
>
> *Slang*. to suffer losses or be disillusioned in business or social relationships:
>
> *She was burned by that phony stock deal.*

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burned) — Sense 27

> ## Has Been Burned
>
> **Meaning/Usage:** To get screwed; to get a bad deal; to be tricked
>
> **Explanation:** When you are burned, it hurts.  When you are screwed, get a bad deal, or get cheated, that hurts too.  So it became common to use "burned" in this manner.

[TalkEnglish.com](http://www.talkenglish.com/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=1092)

**Edit:** I notice in your question you say:

> The word I believe I'm looking for is similar to 'ized' words, in that it describes a state of 'forced distrust' assigned to myself, not the state or act of the object/person breaking the trust (e.g. "I've been/become xxxxxxxized by such-and-such...").

I would say that "I've been burned before" is more a general statement of disillusionment and distrust and doesn't imply a particular instance of "burning" (but it definitely implies that *something* happened).

Comment: This one's pretty good too, ranking just below disillusioned in my book. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have become **jaded**

> Made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by surfeit

Comment: Another one I commonly try to think of. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to disillusioned, you could say you've been ***disabused*** of its integrity:

> to show or convince (someone) that a belief is incorrect
>   (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disabuse)

Or, you could perhaps say you've been ***dismayed*** by it's poor quality:

> to surprise in such a manner as to disillusion
>   (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dismay)

Answer (score 2):

You've been **bitten**, as in 'once bitten, twice shy'. This describes your experience in the past, but also your outlook for the future.

Examples in the technology sector:

> UK government gets bitten by Microsoft Word [(australian news article)](http://www.theage.com.au/articles/2003/07/02/1056825430340.html%20example%20of%20software)
>
> Cisco bitten by Java deserialisation bug, working on patch [(artice by London based IT news and reviews website)](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/12/10/cisco_java_deserialisation_bug/%20Cisco%20and%20Java%20bug)

Comment: I think 'disillusioned' is probably the best 'serious' word and all-rounder, but for popular or colloquial use 'burnt' or 'bitten' convey more emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

i would say that the bugs **dispelled** my confidence, **disabused** me of my trust, and **made me wary** of the system.

> **dispel** (verb): make (a doubt, feeling, or belief) disappear.
>
> **disabuse** (verb): persuade (someone) that an idea or
> belief is mistaken.
>
> **wary** (adjective): feeling or showing caution about possible
> dangers or problems.