# single word for the condition of trust issue due to repeated disappointment in the past

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen the word before but I forgot what it is.
The word is to describe a mental/emotion of a person when the past experience has given him repeated disappointment on a certain thing. The person is getting used to the feeling and adapt to not expecting the high quality outcome.

Comment: You need to provide a sentence that would use the word.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541254/what-is-another-word-for-a-person-who-loses-admiration-love-respect-towards-some/541269?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#541269)   [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341838/term-for-disappointment-beyond-all-expectations/341841?r=SearchResults&s=14|0.0000#341841) [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341709/word-for-when-youve-been-forced-to-no-longer-trust-something-or-someone/341712?r=SearchResults&s=17|0.0000#341712)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word ***jaded*** seems to fit your description.

[Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded):

> 1. fatigued by overwork. EXHAUSTED
> 2. made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by having or seeing too much of something

The second meaning appears to match your exposition.

Answer (score 0):

You could say the person is **disillusioned**.

As [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/disillusioned) defines it:

> having lost faith or trust in something: disappointed that something is not as good, valuable, true, etc., as it had seemed
>
> > She became more and more *disillusione*d with politics